# How can I save an XML file with Unity on the Android platform?

Tags: c#, android, unity, xml

I am writing a game that has a save function which looks like this

```
    public void Save()
    {

        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer ser = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(this.GetType());
        System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(("Assets/Resources/Save");
         ser.Serialize(file, this);
        file.Close();
    }
}
```

This will work fine in the editor and on Windows machines, but when we build to Android the saving no longer works. Why is that?

Comment: No longer works in what way? Are you getting an error?

Comment: From session to session with the game you cannot have a save load, it reverts back to if a there was no save file.

Comment: "*From session to session with the game you cannot have a save load*", well yes, if the file isn't writing, you couldn't load it. "*it reverts back to if a there was no save file*"... huh?

Comment: I have a system where it checks to see if there is a save file, if not it loads so other data a creates a new save file. So it is not saving every time you start the game it creates a new save file. My problem is that it cannot find the XML file to save to.

Comment: If you want to see this and other methods of saving and loading data then there is a paid course you can get for FREE on Udemy. It covers 5 different methods to save and load data in Unity3D. It covers PlayerPrefs, Text files, Binary Serialization, Xml Serialization and even SQLite! The free coupon link for this course is https://www.udemy.com/saving-and-loading-game-data-in-unity3d/?couponCode=UNITY Goodluck!

Answer (score 1):

It's likely to do with the path you're trying to save to and/or the permissions. While I haven't done this myself, all the examples I've seen where people are writing to files in Android, they have to use `Application.persistentDataPath` and append their directory to the end. This ensures you're writing to the correct location, and a location where you have permission to do so.

Answer (score 1):

It's faster to debug in the Editor, so this made my life simple:

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
rootFolder = Application.dataPath+"/RootFolder/";
#elif UNITY_ANDROID || UNITY_IOS
rootFolder = Application.persistentDataPath;
#endif
```

And from the *rootFolder*, you build your file system structure (cross-plateform).